Equation of motion for a Proca field in Robertson Walker metric
this is my very first question, I hope to do everything in a proper way.
The problem I have is about a vector field in a flat-Robertson metric:
\begin{equation}
    d s^2=d t^2-a^2(t)d\vec{x}^2,\quad \sqrt{-g}=a^3
\end{equation}
where $a=a(t)$ is the scale factor.
According to the following references:[1]https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.93.103520 [2] https://doi.org/10.1007/JHEP07%282019%29060
the action of a massive vector field $B^\mu$ can be split in two separate terms one for the longitudinal and one for the transverse (with respect to the comoving momentum $\vec{k}$ ) components:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        S_T&=\int\frac{d t d^3\vec{k} a^3}{\left(2\pi\right)^3}\frac{1}{2a^2}\left[\left|\partial_t\vec{B}_T\right|^2-\left(\frac{k^2}{a^2}+m^2\right)\left|\vec{B}_T\right|^2\right],\\
        S_L&=\int\frac{d t d^3\vec{k} a^3}{\left(2\pi\right)^3}\frac{1}{2a^2}\left[\frac{m^2a^2}{k^2+m^2a^2}\left|\partial_tB_L\right|^2-m^2\left|B_L\right|^2\right]
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
where the time component of the field is not dynamical. This is done by Fourier transforming the field inside the action.
From the two actions is clear how the longitudinal and transverse components evolve differently. In particular the transverse one is basically the same equation for a minimally coupled scalar field.
I really would like to reproduce this result starting from the equation of motion of the vector field:
\begin{equation}
    \nabla_\mu G^{\mu\nu}+m^2B^\nu=0
\end{equation}
Taking the covariant derivative of the above equation I find the following constraint:
\begin{equation}
    \nabla_\mu B^\mu=\partial_0B^0+\frac{3\dot{a}}{a}B^0+a^{-2}\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{B}=0
\end{equation}
The problem I have is the following.

According to ref:https://doi.org/10.1143/PTP.71.309 the derivative term of the equation of motion can be written as:
\begin{equation*}
    \partial^\mu\partial_\mu B_\nu-\partial_\nu\partial^\mu B_\mu+\frac{\dot{a}}{a}G_{0\nu}
\end{equation*}
However according to my calculation I should have:
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        \nabla^\mu G_{\mu\nu}&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\partial^\mu\left(\sqrt{-g}G_{\mu\nu}\right)=\partial^\mu G_{\mu\nu}+G_{\mu\nu}\frac{\partial^\mu\sqrt{-g}}{\sqrt{-g}}\\
        &=\partial^\mu\left(\partial_\mu B_\nu-\partial_\nu B_\mu\right)+\frac{3\dot{a}}{a}G_{0\nu}\\
        &=\partial^\mu\partial_\mu B_\nu-\partial_\nu\partial^\mu B_\mu+\frac{3\dot{a}}{a}G_{0\nu}
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}
where I used the fact that $G^{\mu\nu}$ is anti-symmetric. I find that the term in $\dot{a}/a$ has a factor 3. Even calculating the covariant derivative by brute force with all the Christoffel I found the very same results.

I will not report all the calculation (I don't know if I can) but in the end I find that the equation of motion for the different components of the vector field can be written as:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        &\left(\nabla^2-m^2a^2\right)B_0=\partial_0\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{B},\\
        &\left(\partial^2_0-a^{-2}\nabla^2+\frac{3\dot{a}}{a}\partial_0+m^2\right)B_k-\partial_k\left(\partial_0B_0+a^{-2}\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{B}+\frac{3\dot{a}}{a}B_0\right)=0.
    \end{split}
\end{equation}


Using the constraint $\nabla_\mu B^\mu=0$ I obtain that the equations for the $B_k$ are simply:
\begin{equation*}
    \left(\partial^2_0-a^{-2}\nabla^2+\frac{3\dot{a}}{a}\partial_0+m^2\right)B_k=0
\end{equation*}
that is the same for each $k$. Thus according to my calculation the longitudinal and transverse part evolve in the same way.
The point is, where am I wrong? I made carefully the calculations and the result is always the same. Also I don't understand why the equation in ref:https://doi.org/10.1143/PTP.71.309 has a different factor in $\dot{a}/a$. Maybe my mistake is there and the calculations are plagued from the beginning.
I think I am missing something very easy but I am not able to find it by myself. I hope someone can help me. Thank you.
